# How to add a lists of dictionaries to another dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this dictionary "properties" with a key `livenessTests` and in turn the `livenessTests` is a list of dictionaries.
How do I add/append `livenessTests` to another dictionary `json`?

```
properties = {

'livenessTests': [

{

'name':'http' + '_' + 'livenesstest',

'testObject':'/default.html'

},

{

'name':'https' + '_' + 'livenesstest',

'testObject':'/default.html'

}
]
```

The resulting "json" directory should be something like

```
json : {

"acg": {

"id": "1.87",

"name": "Internal"

},

"asmappings": [],

"cidrMaps": [],

"properties": {"livenessTests" : [{<contents from list above>},
                                  {<contents from list above>}
                                 ] 

              }
```

I am trying this

```
for key in properties.keys():
    print key
    json['properties'].append(property[key])
```

I am getting this error,

```
> json['properties'].append(properties[key])

KeyError: 'properties'
```

What I am doing wrong here ? Sorry new to learning . Thanks

Comment: Since there are answers below, just a minor comment. It's not good to use json as name of a dictionary since there is also a package named json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to look up the key `properties` in `json`, but as you can see in the dictionary you posted there is no key `properties`. If you are looking to create a new list of dictionaries in the `json` dictionary you first need to declare it.

```
json['properties'] = []  # Missing this!

for key in properties.keys():
    print key
    json['properties'].append(property[key])
```

Comment: Sorry, I improved my question to be correct. 
The methods suggested in the answers give

"livenessTests": [
       {
           "name": "http_livenessTest",
           "testObject": "/default.html"
       },       

But I was hoping to get

"properties": [

  {"livenessTests": [
                {
                    "name": "Testing failover",
                    "testObject": "/default.html"
                }
            ],
  }     

Do I need to specify properties as a key somewhere?

Comment: Lol... that was not the question you originally asked.  But ok.

Answer (score 2):

Use the dictionary update method.

```
json.update(properties)
```

Example:

```
properties = {    
'livenessTests': [
    {'name':'http' + '_' + 'livenesstest',
    'testObject':'/default.html'
    },
    {
    'name':'https' + '_' + 'livenesstest',
    'testObject':'/default.html'
    }
]}

json = {"acg": {
    "id": "1-7KLGU.G19717",
    "name": "Akamai Internal-1-7KLGU - 1-7KLGU.G19717"
    },
    "asmappings": [],
    "cidrMaps": [],
    "livenessTests" : []
    }

json.update(properties)
print json
```